# loop skipping some statements

Tags: java, loops, methods

I have written this code to let a clink recognize their records

```
public static void main (String args[]){//Start main
   String [] name = new String [5];
   int [] age = new int [5];
   char [] test = new char [5];
   addPatients( name , age , test );
}

public static void addPatients ( String[] n ,int[] a ,char[] t ){
   i=0;
   while (i<n.length )
   {
      System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Name: ");
      n[i] = scan.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Age: ");
      a[i]=scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Medical test: ");
      t[i]=scan.next().charAt(0);
      i++;
  }

  System.out.println("Enter the patient’s index to find his/her information : ");
  int index= scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println ("Patient name : " + n[index] +"\n Patient age : " + a[index] +"\n Patient    Medical test: " + t[index]);
}
```

but the problem is in the `addPatients`, when the method start working, it only read the first statement

```
 System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Name: ");
 n[i] = scan.nextLine();
```

from user once and skip it in the second loop!

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Are there any errors in particular ?

Comment: @Adarsh the code and the problem are typed clearly

Comment: @ZouZou the code and the problem are typed clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the great explanation that were given so far..... 
So the final modified code to correct this problem is here ...

```
 public static void addPatients ( String[] n ,int[] a ,char[] t )

 {

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;
    while (i<n.length )
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Name: ");
        n[i] = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Age: ");
        a[i]=scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Medical test: ");
        t[i]=scanner.next().charAt(0);
        i++;
        scanner.nextLine(); // To swallow the extra excess newline(enter) character.
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the patient’s index to find his/her information : ");
    final int index= scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("Patient name : " + n[index] +"\n Patient age : " + a[index] +"\n Patient    Medical test: " + t[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) after [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29), as `nextInt` doesn't consume `\n` and it'll be consumed in `nextLine` causing it to "skip" your actual input.

One solution is to add additional `nextLine` after `nextInt` to "swallow" the `\n` that wasn't read via `nextInt`.

So what's happening now in your code is that when you ask for the `int` input, the user types for example 12 and hit enter (`\n`), the `int` value will be read, but when you reach `n[i] = scan.nextLine();` again, the `\n` is waiting to be read.. And it'll be read, so you'll think that it was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you write `scan.next()` to read the patient's medical test, the characters that make up the next word are pulled from the scanner, but the newline character or other whitespace that follows them is not.

For example, if the user has typed P A S S then pressed Enter, the letters P A S and S are read from the scanner, but the newline character remains on the scanner - it will be the next character read.  Then, on the second iteration of the loop, the following call to `scan.nextLine()` just reads that left-over newline character, instead of reading the second patient's name.

After that, everything is out of whack.  The scanner has several characters that haven't been read yet, but should have been.

The solution to this is to add an extra `scan.nextLine()` after `t[i]=scan.next().charAt(0);`, to pull that extra newline character off the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

```
  System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Name: ");
  n[i] = scan.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Age: ");
  a[i]=scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter Patient’s Medical test: ");
  t[i]=scan.next().charAt(0);
  i++;
```

In the above code, you first enter a name and press enter. The name will be stored in n[i] but the newline(enter) is still there as an input waiting to be read. In your age question, you are waiting for an integer, which skips the new line (could be any number of new lines) and waits for the next integer that you input. The next question for Test result waits for the next token . The next() method ignores all new line characters and spaces till it can fetch a complete token. You enter a value here and hit enter. Now this enter is read by your name question as an input in the second run of the loop, as nextLine() does not ignore newlines. So, you can either ignore the newline you hit after your third question by fetching it after every loop. Or you use next() in place of newLine(). By using next(), you can only enter 1 word though.